# Сохранение выбора

Tags: php

Нужно реализовать скриптик который работает по принципу выбора шаблонов на многих порталах и форумах, т.е. выбираешь из списка выбирает 1или2 и записывается в сессию или в куки или в кеш твой выбор, куда нить сохраняется, и при каждом заходе(выходил ли он из браузера или нет) чтоб сохранялся его выбор, как это сделать? на примерчике если можно... (и название переменной чтоб можно было использовать :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вы же сами сказали "сохранить в куки", что вам мешает посмотреть как создаются эти самые "[печеньки](http://www.php.su/functions/?setcookie)". Передаете в куки идентификатор шаблона, а при каждой загрузке сайта проверяете его и применяете нужный шаблон.

Comment: не думал что так легко будет =)